# is it possible to $\int \frac{dx}{(x+1)^2(x^2+1)}$ without partial fractions

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int \frac{dx}{(x+1)^2(x^2+1)}$$
What I tried "-

Let $$x=tan(\theta)$$

so $$dx= sec^2(\theta) d\theta$$
which gives us

$$ \int \frac{sec^2(\theta)}{(1+tan(\theta))^2 sec^2(\theta)}$$

so we have after simplification , the integral of

$$\int \frac{d\theta}{(1+tan(\theta))^2}$$

which I'm unable to integrate further , any advice would be greatly appreciated .

I have considered the weierstrass substitution but I don't think it would be of any help here

thanks!

edit:- I also considered expressing tan in terms of sin and cos, but after that there's no neat sub that works

Comment: Whoever downvoted, please explain why? Should I add more working?

Comment: See tulasi's answer at [Evaluting: $\int\frac{1}{(1+\tan x)^2} dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158591/evaluting-int-frac11-tan-x2-dx) : no partial fractions, but you need to do some trigonometric manipulation if you want to avoid partial fractions.

Comment: Thanks! How did you hyperlink text in the comments by the way?

Comment: `[text](url)`, e.g. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4820125/is-it-possible-to-int-fracdxx12x21-without-partial-fractions). When writing a comment, see the "Help" button that appears at the bottom right of the text box for more info.

Comment: try partial fractions